# How can I reactivate my Twitter account?

Tags: twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to register dead twitter account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/how-to-register-dead-twitter-account)

I've deactivated my twitter account because I wanted another existing account to replace it. Is there any way to reactivate it or use the same email address (and username) for another account?